# PrepareForSegue not sending data between two TableView Controllers

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to pass a test variable to my destination controller, but the test is unsuccessful.

My performsegue is done here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        programKeySegue = programKeys[indexPath.section]

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSelectedProgram", sender: self)
    }
```

My prepareforsegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueSelectedProgam" {
            let selectedProgramVC = segue.destination as! SelectedProgramTableViewController
            selectedProgramVC.programKey = "test" //programKeySegue
        }
    }
```

and in the destination controller:

```
var programKey: String?
```

But when I print(programKey) in viewDidLoad 'nil' is printed to the console. I have used this method before and it has always worked fine. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I tired removing override from prepare for segue, I tried appending self to the performsegue and I have tried assigning different variables to be passed. Nothing has worked.

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue` you have a typo in your segue identifier.

Comment: Thank you! it is working now, although I'm feeling very stupid haha

Comment: You're welcome, I'll vote to close this question as not reproducible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your problem was caused by a typo. You can prevent this in future by not using string comparison…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // If there are multiple segues to this destination, you can  
    // perform a similar check on the source

    if let selectedProgramVC = segue.destination as? SelectedProgramTableViewController
        selectedProgramVC.programKey = "test" //programKeySegue
    }
}
```

Also, you could give use the view controller name as the segue name in the storyboard, and then…

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    programKeySegue = programKeys[indexPath.section]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: String(describing: SelectedProgramTableViewController .self), sender: self)
}
```

et voila… no strings!